# Axios: which HTTP response status codes result in then() and which in catch()?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, axios, http-status-codes

Assume we have the following JavaScript code:

```
axios.get('/some-url')
  .then((response) => {...})
  .catch((error) => {...});
```

By default, which HTTP status codes of the response result in `.then()` being invoked, and which in `.catch()`?

Answer (score 1):

This is determined by the setting `validateStatus`.

By default, this is set as follows in [lib/defaults.js](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js):

```
validateStatus: function validateStatus(status) {
    return status >= 200 && status < 300;
}
```

So, any status codes in the 200's range will result in `.then()` being called, whereas any other status codes, in `.catch()` being called.

It can be changed as follows:

```
let myAxiosInstance = axios.create({
    validateStatus: function (status) {
        return status >= 200 && status < 500;
    }
});
```